# Edit an input file in HTML page with Javascript (without using POST/GET)

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I need to upload the content of a file to a page and parse it and can only use HTML and Javascript to do it. The only ways I know how to do it is through form submission but this is no use for me. Is there any way on Javascript to retrieve the document content from the input div?

```
<input id="fileupload" name="file" type="file" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload/10811427#10811427

Comment: what type of files ? txt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with HTML5 FileApi(or very old IE).
HTML5:

```
<input id="fileupload" name="file" type="file" />
<div></div>
<script>
document.querySelector('#fileupload').addEventListener('change', function(){
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(){
        document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = this.result;
    }
    fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wm8Vs/

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the input, you can use:

`document.getElementById('fileupload').value`

To change the `value` you can do:

`document.getElementById('fileupload').value = some_value`

Comment: I may have not been as clear as I should have, I needed to get the content from the file not the content from the tag (input). This actually shows something like c:\fakepath\filename